# How to access perl console output inside C program?

Tags: c, perl

I have written a C program which embeds a `perl` interpreter.

A Perl script is invoked inside the C program. The Perl script prints output on the console.

How can I access it in my C program?

```
char* perl_script = "D:\\Perl Scripts\\Exif\\Image-ExifTool-8\.69\\exiftool ";
char* file = "D:\\pic2\.jpg";
//char* command_line[] = {"", "-e", "print \"Hello from C!\\n\";"};
char* command_line[] = {"", perl_script, file};
my_perl = perl_alloc();
perl_construct(my_perl);
perl_parse(my_perl, xs_init, 3, command_line, (char **)NULL);
perl_run(my_perl);
```

I am not using a command inside C. I am using `perl_run()`. How can I access console output in this case?

Answer (score 2):

If it's running on GNU/Linux you can use `popen()` and then read it as normal pipe http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen

Answer (score 1):

If that is the only reason you are embedding `perl` in your C program, you might be better off not using it, and using the C library [libexif](http://libexif.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks for showing me a library for exif. But is there a way I can access console output in C?